# Notice: Undefined index: buttonstyle in

Tags: php, html

I am running a `PHP` script and this error shows up when I host the files on my `VPS` but not on a `web-server`.

Here is the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: buttonstyle in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\steamauth\steamauth.php on line 19

And here is the script (C:\xampp\htdocs\steamauth\steamauth.php)

```
<?php
 ob_start();
 session_start();
 require ('openid.php');

 function logoutbutton() {
echo "<form action=\"steamauth/logout.php\" method=\"post\"><input value=\"Logout\" type=\"submit\" /></form>"; //logout button
}

function steamlogin()
{
try {
require("steamauth/settings.php");
$openid = new LightOpenID($steamauth['domainname']);

$button['small'] = "small";
$button['large_no'] = "large_noborder";
$button['large'] = "large_border";
$button = $button[$steamauth['buttonstyle']];

if(!$openid->mode) {
    if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
        $openid->identity = 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid';
        header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
    }
//echo "<form action=\"?login\" method=\"post\"> <input type=\"image\" src=\"http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_".$button.".png\"></form>";
}

 elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
    echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
} else {
    if($openid->validate()) { 
            $id = $openid->identity;
            $ptn = "/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9]{15,25}+)$/";
            preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);

            $_SESSION['steamid'] = $matches[1]; 
            include_once("set.php");
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE steamid='".$_SESSION['steamid']."'");
            if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (steamid) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['steamid']."')") or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());
            }
            if (isset($steamauth['loginpage'])) {
                header('Location: '.$steamauth['loginpage']);
            }
    } else {
            echo "User is not logged in.\n";
    }

}
} catch(ErrorException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
}

?>
```

or (For a better looking version): http://pastebin.com/gEQT0SUW

Here is the code of steamauth/settings.php

```
<?php
 $steamauth['apikey'] = "CANT SAHRE IT. PRIVATE"; // Your Steam WebAPI-Key found at http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey
 $steamauth['domainname'] = "CANT SAHRE IT. PRIVATE"; // The main URL of your website displayed in the login page
 $steamauth['logoutpage'] = ""; // Page to redirect to after a successfull logout (from the directory the SteamAuth-folder is located in) - NO slash at the beginning!
 $steamauth['loginpage'] = "/"; // Page to redirect to after a successfull login (from the directory the SteamAuth-folder is located in) - NO slash at the beginning!
?>
```

Comment: check what `$steamauth` variable contains by printing it out and you will see that value with `buttonstyle index` is not existing. Check it

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, I am new to this :S

Comment: echo `"<pre/>";print_r($steamauth);` do this and show us what it prints?

Comment: Where do I put this?

Comment: Oh man after this `require("steamauth/settings.php");` and check what value its print. put like this `echo "<pre/>";print_r($steamauth);die;`

Comment: This https://gyazo.com/c375b5a8189218b6a90501d6567aac5f

Comment: U don't have $steamauth['buttonstyle'] in this result chk your provided link

Comment: See in your printed array no index with the name `buttonstyle ` exist, tat's why when you are trying to use `$steamauth['buttonstyle']` it giving you error

Comment: What shall I do then?

Comment: Goto steamauth/settings.php file and check how $steamauth generated

Comment: Or add steamauth/settings.php code in question

Comment: This is what is inside settings.php :            http://pastebin.com/Nx9ckn3V

Comment: Instead of link plz add code in yur question yur link is not working in my region

Comment: OK define value of $steamauth['buttonstyle'] in setting.Php that u need

Comment: But how do I do this... I am new to php...

Comment: Chk answer u will get the idea what u need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your setting.Php file there is no index available with `$steamauth['buttonstyle']`.

**Solution:**

What you need define `$steamauth['buttonstyle']` in setting.php file your required value as:

```
$steamauth['apikey'] = "CANT SAHRE IT. PRIVATE";

$steamauth['domainname'] = "CANT SAHRE IT. PRIVATE"; 

$steamauth['logoutpage'] = "";

$steamauth['loginpage'] = "/";

$steamauth['buttonstyle'] = "value that you need"; // add this index
```

Set the value in buttonstyle index that you need for this URL:

```
http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_".$button.".png
```

Comment: @creepycreep Glad to help bro